# How to add a function within a function?

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I have a function to create a plot. However, I would like to include some preprocessing within the function to convert values to labels using the `sjlabelled` package.

```
library(haven)
data <- read_spss("http://staff.bath.ac.uk/pssiw/stats2/SAQ.sav")

library(dplyr)
library(labelled)
library(sjlabelled)
```

```
bar_plot <- function(data, var) {
  
  data %>% 
    as_label(var) %>% 
    filter({{var}} != "Neither") %>% 
    ggplot(aes({{var}})) +
    geom_bar() +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_classic() +
    labs(x = NULL, y = "Count", title = var_label(pull(data, {{var}})))
}
```

```
bar_plot(data, Q01)
```

I'm getting a plot but it is incorrect and I get this error in the console `1 variables were not found in the dataset: var`

I tried using `curly-curly`, `eval`, `!!`, `sym`, `ensym`, but none of them worked.

The problem is with this line: `as_label(var) %>%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `as_label` function captures user input with [deparse and substitute](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#:%7E:text=substitute()%20is%20often%20paired,it%20into%20a%20character%20vector.) You can take a look at the function yourself: `sjlabelled:::as_label.data.frame`, or call it with `debug`.

To get around this, you can use a combination of `do.call` and `ensym` (`enexpr` also works).

```
bar_plot <- function(data, var) {

  data <- do.call(as_label, list(data, ensym(var)))
  
  data %>% 
    filter({{ var }} != "Neither") %>% 
    ggplot(aes({{ var }})) +
    geom_bar() +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_classic() +
    labs(x = NULL, y = "Count", title = var_label(pull(data, {{ var }})))
}


data %>% bar_plot(Q01)
```